# Change section name of an item in content editor based on some rule

Tags: content-editor

I know it might sound crazy,
but is it possible to change the section name in an item depending on some rule.
For instance, Sitecore has B and C templates which are inherited from A template, A has a section "My Section",
but when the user is on an item that is created from template B, this "My Section" should be renamed to "My Section B".

I know it comes from:

```
// Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.EditorFormatter
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager;
using System.Web.UI;

/// <summary>
/// Renders the section.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="section">
/// The section.
/// </param>
/// <param name="parent">
/// The parent.
/// </param>
/// <param name="readOnly">
/// if set to <c>true</c> this instance is read only.
/// </param>
public void RenderSection(Editor.Section section, Control parent, bool readOnly)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(section, "section");
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(parent, "parent");
    bool isSectionCollapsed = section.IsSectionCollapsed;
    bool flag = !isSectionCollapsed || UserOptions.ContentEditor.RenderCollapsedSections;
    RenderSectionBegin(parent, section.ControlID, section.Name, section.DisplayName, section.Icon, isSectionCollapsed, flag);
    if (flag)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < section.Fields.Count; i++)
        {
            RenderField(parent, section.Fields[i], readOnly);
        }
    }
    RenderSectionEnd(parent, flag, isSectionCollapsed);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

this it an old article but seems like relevant
https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/use-a-checkbox-to-control-section-visibility-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms